# Issue in inbound policy for custom authentication

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I have issue in `when` condition of this custom authentication in inbound policy, I tried various method to find out, I couldn't able to identify, API inside the send-request and send-request code itself working fine.

```
<send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="authResponse" timeout="60" ignore-error="false">
            <set-url>@("my_url")</set-url>
            <set-method>GET</set-method>
            <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
                <value>@("Bearer " + context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", ""))</value>
            </set-header>
</send-request>
<choose>
            <when condition="@((int)((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)context.Variables["authResponse"]).Property("StatusCode").Value == 200)">
                <!-- Continue with the API call -->
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized" />
                    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                        <value>application/json</value>
                    </set-header>
                    <set-body>
                        {
                            "errorMessage": "Authentication failed"
                        }
                    </set-body>
                </return-response>
            </otherwise>

</choose>
```

I tried this as well, but this not working

```
<when condition="@((int)context.Variables["authResponse.StatusCode"] == 200)">
                <!-- Continue with the API call -->
</when>
```

Response I recieve is this, the API as no issue

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Internal server error",
    "activityId": "91c498c2-a213-4f38-bb38-494c331bc46e"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below policy to set the `when condition` for status code.

```xml
<inbound >
    <base />
    <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="authResponse" timeout="60" ignore-error="false">
        <set-url>@("my_url")</set-url>
        <set-method>GET</set-method>
        <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
            <value>@("Bearer " + context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", ""))</value>
        </set-header>
    </send-request>
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(((IResponse)context.Variables["authResponse"]).StatusCode==200)>
            <!-- Added response for Testing -->
            <return-response>
                <set-body>Successfully Authenticated...</set-body>
            </return-response>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized" />
                <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                    <value>application/json</value>
                </set-header>
                <set-body>Authentication Failed...</set-body>
            </return-response>
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
</inbound>
```

By using `<when condition="@(((IResponse)context.Variables["authResponse"]).StatusCode==200)>`, I am able to get the expected response as shown below.

[image]

***Trace***-

[image]

Comment: @BLNT Hope this works for you

Comment: for some reason I'm getting 500 StatusCode for authResponse, but when i run it in postman I get 200, I'm not sure why as in send-request. There is no issue in API

Comment: Are you using the same policy? please check the endpoint and token or you can also get the more details about the error message in trace

Comment: @BLNT try to check the error in trace

Comment: i traced it, I'm getting 500, is my send-request looks fine, there is issue in that part i believe

Comment: Can you share the screenshots of the trace

Comment: I tried hard coding the header it works fine in policy, we need to fetch the Authorization token from request and send it as header to the API as in code, Bearer prefix is already included so we don't need to add it. the way I'm doing is okay but not perfect but there is some syntax issue, I'm trying to solve this part, not sure what is the exact way.

Comment: @BLNT can you please share the screenshots how you are trying it or testing it in Apim. While testing, you need to pass the token in the header. It will be easier to help you better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255961/discussion-between-blnt-and-ikhtesam-afrin).