# Read a secret key from azure key vault in apim

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-api-management, hmac

i need to validate a hmac in my apim policy. For which the hmac secret will be stored in azure key vault. Below are the steps that i will be following in my policy

- Read the secret key from the key vault
- Validate the hmac

Below is the apim policy that i tried

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />

        <!-- Fetch HMAC key from Key Vault -->
        <set-variable name="keyVaultSecretUri" value="KV_URL/secrets/SECRET_NAME" />
        <set-variable name="keyVaultClientId" value="KV_CLIENT />
        <set-variable name="keyVaultClientSecret" value="KV_SECRET" />

        <set-variable name="request" value="@{
            var keyVaultSecretUri = context.Variables["keyVaultSecretUri"];
            var keyVaultClientId = context.Variables["keyVaultClientId"];
            var keyVaultClientSecret = context.Variables["keyVaultClientSecret"];

            return new {
                method = "GET",
                url = keyVaultSecretUri,
                headers = new {
                    Authorization = "Bearer " + FetchAccessToken(keyVaultClientId, keyVaultClientSecret)
                }
            };
        }" />

        <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="keyVaultResponse" timeout="20" ignore-error="false">
            <set-url>@(context.Variables["request"].url)</set-url>
            <set-method>@(context.Variables["request"].method)</set-method>
            <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
                <value>@(context.Variables["request"].headers.Authorization)</value>
            </set-header>
        </send-request>

        <!-- Log Key Vault Response -->
        <trace source="keyVault" severity="information">
            <message>@(context.Variables["keyVaultResponse"].Body?.ToString())</message>
        </trace>
    </inbound>
</policies>
```

Below is the error i got

```
 One or more fields contain incorrect values:
Error in element 'set-variable' on line 22, column 10: The name 'FetchAccessToken' does not exist in the current context
Error in element 'send-request' on line 36, column 10: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'url' and no extension method 'url' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error in element 'trace' on line 45, column 10: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Body' and no extension method 'Body' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

in the above policy i am just trying to read the secret and display. I am unable to achieve that. I followed [this link](https://www.svenmalvik.com/azure-apim-key-vault/) as a reference

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin - I have updated the error in the question

Comment: What is your requirement, you want to fetch the secret value stored in Key Vault from APIM? If so, you can do that using Named value

Comment: I want get the secret key and use it for a hmac validation in my policy @IkhtesamAfrin

Comment: You can use `validate-jwt` to validate the token

Comment: Is hmac credentials are stored in key vault or token is stored? Are you fetching the token from key vault and validating it in APIM using openid-config url?

Comment: the token will passed as a header ,I am just going to store the secret key in key vault , get the key from keyvault and then use it for validation in apim policy @IkhtesamAfrin

Comment: are you trying to do in [this](https://i.imgur.com/Om5UHZx.png) way.

Comment: No I am trying to do the below
1. get the token from header value
2. get the secret from keyvault
3.validate the hmac token, if valid pass apim if not throw error

I do not know if its the correct way. Kindly guide @IkhtesamAfrin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255964/discussion-between-ikhtesam-afrin-and-sindhu1990).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am just trying to read the secret and display

To fetch the secret value from Key Vault, you need to do the following setup.

1. Enable the Managed Identities like below in Azure APIM.

[image]

2. Grant Get Secret access to APIM in Key vault using Access Policies as shown below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

3. Create a Named value in APIM.

[image]
[image]

Once the named value is created, then you can use the below policy to fetch the secret and display the value too.

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base  />
        <set-variable  name="KeyVaultSecret"  value="{{Named value name}}"  />
        <return-response>
            <set-body>@("Key Vault Secret is: "+(context.Variables["KeyVaultSecret"])+"")</set-body>
        </return-response>
    </inbound>
</policy>
```

I am able to get the Key Vault secret value.

[image]

You need to use the `<send-request>` policy like below-

```xml
<send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="keyVaultResponse" timeout="60" ignore-error="true">
    <set-url>@("pass_the_url")</set-url>
    <set-method>GET</set-method>
    <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
        <value>@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", ""))</value>
    </set-header>
</send-request>
```

You can also refer to my answer in this [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77492543/issue-in-inbound-policy-for-custom-authentication/77492837#77492837).

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. Can i do this without the name value? what if my secret key is dynamic? for eg my secret key name will change like secretkey1, secretkey2 , etc Is it possible to read such keys in apim?

Comment: APIM automatically refreshes Key Vault secrets every 4 hours: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-properties?tabs=azure-portal#key-vault-secrets. To avoid breaking validation for 4 hours once you update the secret, you can store two secrets, accept the call if either secret validates the signature, but when it's time to update - only update the one that was least recently used to sign.

Comment: I am asking like ill know only the key name during run time. So can i read the value instead of storing it as a name value? because this approach seems to be for static data